# state management with vue3 module federation error

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3, quasar-framework, webpack-module-federation

bootstrap:24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)
at fn (hot module replacement:61)
at Module../node_modules/quasar/src/plugins/Platform.js (lang.js:100)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)
at fn (hot module replacement:61)
at Module../node_modules/quasar/src/install-quasar.js (icon-set.js:60)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)
at fn (hot module replacement:61)
at Module../node_modules/quasar/src/vue-plugin.js (uid.js:72)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)

Comment: Could you please add some more details about what are you trying to achieve and what is not working?

Comment: I got the answer need to add shared array but still facing problem with store. How can I add state management(store) in module federation. Please help me.